# Getting different movie info from script than from python shell

Tags: python, shell, imdb, imdbpy

I have following script to output the cast of a movie to a text document:

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()
movie = ia.get_movie(0111161)
cast = movie['cast']
text_file = open("Cast.txt", "w")
text_file.write("{0}".format(movie))
text_file.write("{0}".format(cast))
text_file.close()
```

As you can see I scrape it from IMDB website not from a database.
When I execute this script in the python shell (2.7.13) I get the cast of 'The Shawshank Redemption', but when I execute it from command line (python myscript.py), I get the cast of the movie '29 Acacia Avenue', with id=0037489.
How can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

`movie = ia.get_movie("0111161")`

instead of

`movie = ia.get_movie(0111161)`

Answer (score 4):

`0111161` starts with 0 and therefore Python interprets it as an **octal** number. Its value in decimal is 37489.